# Jpa maximum value request

Tags: spring, postgresql, jpa

```
    @Query(value = "SELECT t FROM Tournament t   "
        + "LEFT JOIN t.participants p ON t.id = p.tournament.id "
        + "WHERE t.status <> 'CANCELED' "
        + "AND p.userId = :id "
        + "AND t.startedAt < :now "
        + "AND t.endAt < :now  "
        + "AND  t.endAt = (SELECT MAX(t.endAt) FROM Tournament t) "
)
List<Tournament> findUserLastTournament(@Param("id") String id, @Param("now") long now);



@Table(name = "tournaments")
public class Tournament {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

@NonNull
@Column(nullable = false)
private Long startedAt;

@NonNull
@Column(nullable = false)
private Long endAt;

@Column(nullable = false)
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private TournamentStatus status;

@OneToMany
@JsonIgnore
private List<TournamentParticipant> participants = new ArrayList<>();
}


@Table(name = "participants")
public class TournamentParticipant {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NonNull
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String userId;

    @ManyToOne
    private Tournament tournament;
}
```

In the code I have tournaments and their participants, I want to write a request that will return the last tournament in which the player participated. I think the problem is in the participants. The request returns an empty sheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the error is on the last part of the query

SELECT MAX(t.endAt) FROM Tournament t

You are getting last tournament but not observing if the player plays the tournament or not and whether the tournament is cancelled or not